# Equally sized parantheses despite use of \left( ... \right

Tags: math-mode, brackets, delimiters

I think my problem is rather simple but I cannot find the mistake here. I want to have several parantheses in an `align` environment, so I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left( f(x) \right)\\
(f(x))
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, both lines in the PDF look exactly the same, while I expected the outer parentheses in the first line to be a bit bigger. How do I use `\left( ... \right)` correctly here?

Comment: `\left...\right` does not automatically grow the size, but picks a size that fits.  If you wish to grow it, you could use `\bigl(f(x)\bigr)`.  In many ways, the use, when possible, of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg` are preferable to the `\left...\right` syntax.

Comment: How does it determine what size "fits"? Of course in my actual document I have a longer mathematical expression where bigger parentheses seem to look much better, at least to me.

Comment: That comes with experience. As a newcomer you'l probably just have to try them. Remember the manual versions come in four sizes `\big\Big\bigg\Bigg` and it is recommended to use the `\...l` and `\...r` variants (as in `\Bigl(...\Bigr)` otherwise the spacing in relation to other programmes may be wrong